# Go to page textbox for User Reputation Leagues

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues

The paging on the User Reputation Leagues is very helpful, but sometimes if you're trying to page through the data to different points/pages it can be very limiting requiring 20-30 page loads at the max page size (50) to get to the middle pages.

I would like to see a "Go to page:" text box to be able to jump to another page of your choice. Yes, I know (at this time) you can just modify the page number in the URL, but that may not always be the case in the future.

Comment: "but that may not always be the case in the future" You have made me curious, what else would be possibly do instead?

Comment: It could change to a record offset or could possibly get removed from the query string altogether. The idea of the text box being that it is a unified experience for the user who would then have no need to worry about the implementation details.

Comment: Can I promise we'd never do that instead? :)  Also keep in mind your theoretical scenario means that people couldn't link to the leagues properly either, again not something we'd break.

Answer (score 1):

If we broke things in this theoretical scenario or removing it from the URL, we'd also be breaking the ability to link to anything other than the first page of any league.

We won't do that, so I don't think a text box is necessary here.